# Grouping Rows at the top of the table based on search criteria in Datatables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Hello Everyone,
Above is my sample html table.
I am using datatables. Now what I want is:
I want to show group of rows at the top of the datatables based on a search criteria. But still the rows which DO NOT match the search criteria should be shown at the bottom of the table.
And search criteria will be regex based. So more than one values for single column will be searched at the same time.

For example: If I search By Name: "Garrett Winters | Ashton Cox" (regex search)
Than these two rows MUST be shown at the top of the table, and remaining rows which DO NOT match the search criteria must be shown there after the two rows.

I have searched many things,but could not find the solutions.
Also referred this : https://datatables.net/blog/2016-12-22. But this seems a bit different.

As of now I am displaying normal datatable using ".draw()"

I hope you all understood my problem.
Any help appreciated.

Thank you All.

Comment: You are trying to override default `filter` behaviour of datatables. Datatables comes with the default behaviour of filtering the rows.

Comment: You have to disable the basic search/filter option of Datatable and implement your own to display and sort the rows

Comment: Will try on that. Thanks  Krishna Kuntala and Didi.